# Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как из input столбца сделать input строчку

Tags: python, input

из этого Test input в столбец:

1. 1
2. 2
3. -1
4. 0

нужно получить Test input: 1 2 -1 0

Comment: вообще ничего не понятно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например (хотя до конца вопрос и не понятен):

```
result = []
while True:
    item = input()
    if not item:
        break
    result.append(item)
print(*result, sep=' ')
```

Ввод-вывод:

```
 1
 2
 -1
 0
 
1 2 -1 0
```